# Populate a Select Box with Eagerloading

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Any idea what the best way would be to populate a select box with eagerloading?

For example:  I can eagerload a hasOne relation like so which works fine for showing the initial status.

```
Order Model

public function status()
{
  return  $this->hasOne('OrderStatus','id','status');
}
```

But then on the order page I also need to populate a select box with all statuses so a user can change the order status.

```
Order Status Model

public function allStatuses()
{
    return OrderStatuses::all();
}
```

and then I try calling with the dot notation, but that does not work

```
$order::with('orderStatus','orderStatus.allStatuses')->whereId(1000)->get();
```

Basically, my views contain a lot of drop-down for things like country, state, etc.  I know I can send them through the view with multiple variables, but I would like to just call everything in one collection to the view if possible.

I know the above is probably wrong, but any suggestion on the best way to do this would be appreciated.

Right now I am calling all my common selects from a service provider and then import my repos into that so I can call directly from my view like FormList::getStates(), FormList::getCountries(), etc..  Not sure if this is the best way.

Comment: Another option if you have some prefined statuses for your orders, just create a facade/class that will only return an array of ids/statuses that you are going to map inside the database. So you are not going to query the database to retrieve this list.

Comment: @akad0  Thanks.  Yeah, thats kind of how I have it setup now. I setup a separate provider class and facade  with a method for each select list I need. I then import my repos into that class.   I then can just call it into the view. (e.g FormList::getCategories()), makes it easy to cache these methods, but not sure if this is the correct way , so was considering eagerloading the data.  Curious to how others are doing this.

Comment: There is not a right/wrong way to achieve something. There might be more efficient problems , but as long as it's working right, then in a sense it works just fine. Eager loading is not a magic mysterious thing, it's just a wrapper for an optimized sql query. Even eager loading has to execute one query to get the instance and another one to load the relationships. So in a sense you are executing 2 queries through one method. Separating these queries will not make your app slower. Eloquent is just there to make queries easier to write/read